# nature of a linear transformation over infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**The following question is a PhD entrance question.**

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ denote the real vector space of sequences $(x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ of real numbers. Define a linear transformation $T :\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \to  \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ by $$(x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots) \to  (x_0 + x_1, x_1 + x_2, x_2 + x_3, \ldots)$$ Which one of the following statements is correct?

(a) The kernel of T is infinite dimensional.

(b) The image of T is infinite dimensional.

(c) The quotient vector space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}/T (\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}})$ is infinite dimensional.

(d) None of the above.

**Letting $T(x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (0, 0, 0, \ldots)$ implies $(x_0 + x_1, x_1 + x_2, x_2 + x_3, \ldots) = (0, 0, 0, \ldots)$. Hence, we have $x_0 + x_1 = x_1 + x_2 = x_2 + x_3 = \ldots = 0$. Therefore, $(x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots) = x_0 (1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots)$ i.e. $Ker(T) = <(1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots)>$. So, $\ker(T)$ is single dimensional. Hence option (a) is discarded. It seems that the quotient space is also single dimensional but I am not getting any clue to show it. $Image(T)$ is infinite dimensional I think. Since, we can't use rank nullity theorem or the dimension theorem for quotient spaces here, how can we conclude these things. Given that option (b) is correct.**

Comment: Plug in $e_1, e_2$ and so on

Comment: I hope you know but just in case.. $e_n$ is element with $1$ at $n$th place and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: thanks! for the suggestion. What about the quotient space?

Comment: If $v_0 = ((-1)^n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$, so that $\ker(T)=\mathbb R.v_0$, then if $f\colon \mathbb R^\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ is a linear functional with $f(v_0)\neq 0$, then $\mathbb R^\mathbb N = \ker(T)\oplus \ker(f)$, and so the image of $T$ is the image of $\ker(f)$. If you pick any easy-to-compute $f$, it is not hard to see if $(y_n) \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is in the image of $\ker(f)$.

Comment: @user_1729 if you find range then you can find quotient space very easily. Did you find range?